# Как сосчитать количество определенных элементов в списке c#?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть список, состоящий из объектов. Все эти объекты отличаются значением одного поля. Задача состоит в том, чтобы вывести количество объектов для каждого значения этого поля.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему. Приведите пример кода.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Пусть список называется list, а поле по которому считаем называется Name, тогда

```
var result = list.GroupBy(n => n.Name).Select(m => new {m.Key, Count = m.Count()});
```

Это у нас будет LINQ вариант, на тот случай если не захотите создавать свой "велосипед", а воспользуетесь штатными средствами языка. В противном случае @rdorn дал отличный ответ.

Comment: После фигурной скобки поставьте обычную, а то народ любит тут копипастить))

Answer (score 8):

Наивный алгоритм:

1. Создаем `Dictionary` со значением проверяемого поля в качестве ключа
   и счетчиком найденных объектов в качестве значения
2. Для каждого объекта объекта из списка:

   - Добавляем новую запись в `Dictionary`, если обнаруженный ключ отсутствует.
   - Увеличиваем счетчик найденного значения на единицу если ключ уже есть в `Dictionary`.
3. Выводим значения счетчиков `Dictionary`

**UPD**
Сложность алгоритма порядка O(N), где N - длина списка. Согласно **[исходникам](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0)** `Dictinary` использует хеширование ключей и сложность поиска по ключу порядка O(1).

Comment: Поиск в `Dictionary` O(1), так что общая асимптотика должна быть O(N). Использование `HashTable` не должно давать выигрыша.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, перепроверю и поправлю.

Comment: @VladD исправил, приятно что теперь можно полагаться не только на слова. Меня помниться очень упорно убеждали в обратном где-то год назад, и надо сказать успешно, поэтому и засомневался.

Comment: Возможно, те. кто убеждал вас, перепутали с `std::map` из C++, там не хеш-таблица, а дерево.